# Exiting from a Kernel#loop

Tags: ruby

In [Kernel#loop documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), there is an example that uses `break` in order to break out of the loop. Otherwise, the documentation talks about rasing a `StopIteration` error.

I tried them both:

```
i=0
loop do
  puts i
  i+=1
  break if i==10
end

i=0
loop do
  puts i
  i+=1
  raise StopIteration if i==10
end
```

The output is the same. Are there differences between the two approaches? I think that there should be, otherwise why bother to define an error class and all the managements that come with it?

Comment: They seem identical behavior-wise, but raising `StopIteration` is much slower.

Comment: this puzzles me even more on the reason that makes the authors introducing this error, along with the need of managing the exception and to document it. And another related question is about what actually is a break inside a block.

Comment: When you have an enumerator, e.g `e = [1, 2].each`, and then call `loop; e.next; end` you depend on the enumerator raising `StopIteration`. That's a case when a `break` is no appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

`break` is a keyword in ruby, which terminates the most internal loop, whether it be `loop`, or `for`, and a few more (see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm)).

`StopIteration` is an exception, which is caught by `Kernel.loop` (see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/StopIteration.html)).

So in your scenario, they are the same, but in a different scenario, they will act differsntly:

```
puts "first run"
for i in 0..20 do
  puts i
  break if i==10
end
puts "first done"

puts "second run"
for i in 0..20 do
  puts i
  raise StopIteration if i==10
end
puts "second done" # <= will not be printed
```

Here is a scenario where `StopIteration` can be utilized when `break` cannot:

```
puts "first run"

def first_run(i) # will not compile
  puts i
  break if i==10
end

i=0
loop do
  first_run(i)
  i+=1
end

puts "first done"

puts "second run"
def second_run(i)
  puts i
  raise StopIteration if i==10
end

i=0
loop do
  second_run(i)
  i+=1
end

puts "second done"
```

Here is another use-case, which uses the fact the [`Enumerator.next`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) throws a `StopIteration` error when the Enumerator has reached the end:

```
enum = 5.times.to_enum
loop do
  p enum.next
end
```

will print

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Thanks [Cary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) for this example.

Comment: i get your point Uri, but I'm quite doubful about the example you provided to support it. Here it seems that the 'for' loop isn't equipped to manage the exception, so, not providing any special management (in the "loop" the error is meant to be a conscious way of breaking it: the loop stops but the exception isn't re-raised!) it behaves like a standard exception that is: breaks out and stops the processing of the whole script; that doesn't seem to be what a user expects when it jumps out a for loop. So the example seems to rather demonstrate that StopIteration isn't applicable to for loops.

Comment: @AgostinoX - gave another example, which gives a (quite remote) use case for `StopIteration`

Comment: I suggest you add an example such as the following, which illustrates a very common use of `loop`: `enum = 5.times.to_enum #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 5:times>:each>; loop do; p enum.next; end` prints `0,1,2,3,4`'

Comment: @uri, I consider the second example more a bad practise than a real use case, infact it would work with ANY exception not just stop iteration. So it doesn't work because how it's specifically designed. it works because any non caught exception will halt the program execution. And of course you cannot put a break inside a regular def because that way you would assume that the def is called from inside a block, this is a non acceptable assumption! About the third case, where is the evidence that a StopIteration has been thrown?

Comment: @AgostinoX - you are inaccurate. 'loop' catches (only) StopIteration exception, so any other exception would result in a halting of the program, but with StopIteration it will _exit the loop_. As for the third use case, I don't understand why you need evidence... You could either call 'next' on an empty Enumerator, or maybe _read the... manual_

Answer (score 1):

There are two uses of the `break` keyword.

First: the `break` keyword, when in a block, causes the method that the block was passed to to return. If you pass an argument to `break`, the return value of the method will be that argument. Here is an example:

```
def a
  puts 'entering method a'
  yield
  puts 'leaving method a'
end

result = a { break 50 }
puts result
```

This will print:

```
entering method a
50
```

Second: the `break` keyword can cause a `while`, `until`, or `for` loop to terminate. Here is an example:

```
i = 0
result =
  while i < 5
    i += 1
    puts i
    break 75 if i == 3
  end
puts result
```

This will print:

```
1
2
3
75
```

Your example with `Kernel#loop` makes use of the first case, causing the `loop` method to return.

`StopIteration` is an exception which *only* works with `Kernel#loop` as far as I can tell. For example:

```
infinite_loop = Enumerator.new do |y|
  i = 0
  while true
    y << i
    i += 1
  end
end

infinite_loop.each do |x|
  puts x
  raise StopIteration if x == 4
end
```

Fails because `StopIteration` is uncaught, however:

```
x = 0
loop.each do
  puts x
  x += 1
  raise StopIteration if x == 4
end
```

Catches `StopIteration` and exits.

Comment: very interesting the distinction of break in blocks and in 'regular' (non Proc based) loops like while and until. Perhaps NOT in 'for' that seems to be Proc based it too. Have you got an idea of why they introduced 'another way', maybe confusing, of exiting the loop?

Comment: @AgostinoX It is because `Enumerator#next` raises StopIteration, which means you can use `loop` along with `Enumerator#next` and not have to check to see when the enumerator has run out of things. Other exceptions wouldn't work for this because they are not caught by `loop`; they would terminate the program rather than return from `loop`. `break` would also not work for this because the keyword has to be in the block passed to `loop` rather than in a method called by the block passed to `loop`.

Comment: By the way, `for` is not internally "Proc-based", it just looks that way because of the "do" syntax. The MRI interpreter treats it just like `while` and `until`.

Comment: An example to illustrate @Adrian's point just above: `x = 0; for i in [1,2] do x+=1 end; puts x #=> 2`.